# how to reparameterize collection type

Tags: scala, scala-collections, implicit, generic-programming, implicit-typing

I want to define a transformation of a generic collection.

```
def transform[S<:GenIterable[T],T](s:S):S = s.zipWithIndex
```

This throws:

```
type mismatch; found : scala.collection.GenIterable[(T, Int)] required: S
```

I have to declare `S` as a parameterized `GenIterable` in the function definition.  I'd like to specify an output type of "whatever the collection type was that created `S`, except parameterized with `[(T,Int)]`", so that I'm guaranteed to get the same collection type back, and not just `GenIterable`.

**How can I make that happen?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's my stub on it:

```
def transform[S[T]<: GenIterableLike[T,S[T]],T](s:S[T])
  (implicit bf:CanBuildFrom[S[T],(T,Int),S[(T,Int)]]):S[(T,Int)] = {

  s.zipWithIndex
}
```

Signature is horrible, it may be somewhat simplified (or obscured) by replacing `T` with `_`.

Trying it out:

```
scala> val m = Map("x"->"1","y"->"2")
m: scala.collection.Map[String,String] = Map(x -> 1, y -> 2)

scala> transform(m)
res3: Iterable[((String, String), Int)] = List(((x,1),0), ((y,2),1))

scala> val s = Set("x", "y")
s: scala.collection.Set[String] = Set(x, y)

scala> transform(s)
res4: scala.collection.Set[(String, Int)] = Set((x,0), (y,1))

scala> val seq = List("x", "y")
seq: List[String] = List(x, y)

scala> transform(seq)
res5: List[(String, Int)] = List((x,0), (y,1))
```

The key is to use `Like` trait because it carries the type of the collection being used. Then, implicit conversions take care of the rest. Note, how `Map` is handled. It seems that implicit conversions default to converting `Iterable` to `List`, which makes sense.

Comment: Yo dawg, way to scala it up!